# Firebase cloud messaging server - how to subscribe device to a topic using new HTTP v1 api

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently FCM server provides these raw server protocol:

- FCM HTTP v1 API
- Legacy HTTP protocol
- Legacy XMPP Protocol

I using new HTTP v1 API but I find only one endpoint for send messages in this api

> https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project_id/messages:send

I need to sign a device on a topic. But I find only legacy http endpoint

> https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/nKctODamlM4:CKrh_PC8kIb7O...clJONHoA/rel/topics/movies

with other Authorization key. Is it possible to subscribe device to a topic using new HTTP v1 api.

Comment: At this time, the `iid.googleapis.com` endpoint is the only HTTP endpoint for subscribing to topics. If you're using a Node.js server, you can use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/manage-topic-subscriptions) to subscribe to topics, but under the hood this uses the same `iid.googleapis.com` endpoint.